# wrong height of display: table in opera - box model issue?

Tags: html, opera, css

In Opera, it seems that the height of `display: table` is wrong. In the following example, the *outer* height of the div is 100px, while it should be 160px:

```
#a1 {
        background-color: #66f;
        padding: 30px;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        display: table;
}

<div id="a1"></div>
```

Looks like old box model of IE? But IE7/8 works OK in this case.

Feel free to play with http://jsfiddle.net/mpGqU/

Comment: You misunderstand the box-model issue of IE. It would add the padding to the width to make it 160x160, not the other way around. if you want it to be 160x160, you should define it as 160x160.

Comment: @MetalFrog, no, it is *you* who now confused it the other way around. By the CSS standard, the outer dimensions of this div should be 160x160. Old IE box model would make 100x100. Opera now makes 160x100, oddly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Opera (CORE-10163). Removing `display:table;` will fix the problem in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please post a link to the bugreport? Simple google query didn't make it.

Comment: Seems I cannot access bugs.opera.com without registering? Please post the link to the resource.

Comment: Opera's bug tracking system is limited to employees, unfortunately. Linking to it wouldn't do any good. When the desktop team and core team announce new releases, however, they usually include the bug numbers. (We're working to make our bug tracking system more transparent, but it will take some time.)

Comment: OK, it would be good. It seemed strange to me, coming from the open(source) world. Thanks for your answer!